# puedo usar algunos de estos elementos en windows form?

Tags: windows-forms

hola estoy intentando pasar un formulario metro framework a windows form y lo que me pasa esque quiero hacer algo similar a lo que hacia en metro framework o buscar algun elemento similar. lo que tenia era lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema de la barras no hay en windows form, habría algun elemento parecido?

Comment: de que barras hablas? del slider?

Comment: si? ese slider hay algun elemento parecido?

Comment: si.. un winforms tiene un slider... igual, no hubiera sido mejor pasar de metro a wpf? tiene mas control sobre la view

Comment: wpf requiere de librerias externas?

Comment: no se que sean librerias externas.. wpf es otro modo de diseño dentro de .net

Comment: Investiga acerca de `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx`: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) .